# Want to change a timestamp date to an integer YYYYMMDD

Tags: datetime, type-conversion, sybase-sql-anywhere

I have this input "2017-07-21 15:31:04.853453" and I want it to return "20170721" as output.  How can I do it using `cast` or `convert` function?

My column input is the current time (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).

From `cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date)` I have the output "2017-07-24", then I can do several concatenates with substrings. It should work but I wonder if there isn't any other way to get "integer YYYYMMDD".

Answer (score 1):

As [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) mentioned, this works in SQL Anywhere:

```
select CONVERT(char(8),current_timestamp,112) from dummy
```